# What size ground wire is required for a 14-50 outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have installed a 14-50 Bryant outlet with 6/3 plus a 10 gauge ground. However I am going to use it on my welder with an adapter cord from 14-50 to 6-50 connection.  With that said I only have a 10 gauge ground wire and when I measure the adapter cord it doesn't use the neutral 6 gauge wire but rather the ground 10 gauge to complete the circuit. I am thinking I should have used 6/4 wire rather than 6/3 with ground. Your thoughts?

Comment: Will need an expert, but usually ground can be smaller since it is not suppose to carry current except for a few seconds when stuff goes wrong.  Do not know if 10 gauge would be too small and you would want 8 gauge.

Answer (score 6):

According to [NEC 250.122](https://up.codes/viewer/new_york/nfpa-70-2017/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#250.122) 10 AWG copper ground is correct.

(Note that hot and neutral wire sizes are based on NM-B cable. With individual wires smaller sizes are possible in many cases.)

A 14-50 uses two hots, neutral and ground. So it needs 6 AWG x 3 (hots and neutral) and 10 AWG x 1 (ground). Unless it is a 14-50 used as a 40A receptacle (which is legitimate) and connected to a 40A breaker, and then it can be 8 AWG x 3 + 10 AWG x 1.

A 6-50 uses two hots and ground. *It does not use neutral.* It needs 6 AWG x 2 + 10 AWG x 1. A proper 16-50 -> 14-50 adapter connects hots to hots and ground to ground and does not do anything with the 14-50 neutral.

I think the confusion comes about because of all the situations (some legal, some not) where neutral and ground are combined. But 6-50 does not use neutral **at all**, so that is not an issue. In fact, if a 6-50 -> 14-50 adapter connected ground (6-50) to neutral *and* ground (14-50) it would cause a lot of problems.

The reason a ground wire (whether the 4th wire in a 14-50 or the 3rd wire in a 6-50, etc.) can often be smaller than the hot and neutral wires is that the ground wire generally carries no current at all under normal usage. (There are certain exceptions to enable use of a 15A or 20A circuit to power a smart switch without a neutral in an old switch box, but those are *limited* exceptions and not an issue here.) The ground wire normally carries significant current only in a failure situation - e.g., hot shorting to grounded metal case of a device. In those situations, the ground wire doesn't need to carry current for a long time, so heating up wires inside cables/conduit simply isn't a concern. The ground carries current just long enough to trip the circuit breaker. I believe that's also why steel conduit can function as a ground in many situations, even though it is [on the order of 1/10 as conductive as copper](https://www.taisin.com.sg/electrical-conductivity/) - it doesn't have to be as good as copper or aluminum wire, it just has to be "good enough".

Comment: @Herman with this answer in mind can you  please edit your question and better explain what you mean that you measured and found it uses the 10 gauge wire to complete the circuit?  It should not be doing that.  Perhaps you didn't actually mean that, and if you think after reading this answer, that the welder is correctly wired as described here, please modify the question accordingly.  You may also, if you wish, vote up this answer and if it helps you move forward, you can Accept it.

Comment: @jay613 I think OP's statement is extremely clear - the 3rd wire (i.e., besides the hots) of the 6-50 when routed through the adapter comes out on the 10 AWG ground wire from the 14-50. That is correct. That is as it should be. No ambiguity.

Comment: I was confused by "to complete the circuit" but I think you are correct.

Comment: I think OP had 6/3 without ground and added a separate ground wire to the circuit.  Unless there is a 6/6/6/10 cable.

Comment: @crip659 6/3 with ground is readily available - e.g., https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-125-ft-6-3-Black-Stranded-Romex-SIMpull-CU-NM-B-W-G-Wire-63950002/202316279#overlay